# How do you become an e-newsletter service provider?

Tags: email, web-applications, newsletter

One of my clients wants to have an e-newsletter sending out to their clients, I suggest them to use one of the e-newsletter service providers, but they don't want to pay a monthly fee and are thinking of hosting the e-newsletter software themselves and may provide the e-newsletter service to their clients in the future.

Can someone share me some light on how would you go with hosting an e-newsletter programme yourself/become an e-newsletter provider? Where can we buy the e-newsletter software/programme? How do we host it?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Most software is cloud/service based, it makes sense to do it that way. Ultimately you are paying for the sending and processing of emails, subscribers, the server bandwith, and the behind the scenes expertise ensuring your deliverability. (Mass email sending is not as simple as hitting send on Outlook)

If you are looking for a cheaper option that uses more of your own resources/code, you should look into transactional email services like SendGrid, Mailgun or Mandrill. They pretty much rely on API, while marketing/bulk email services like Campaign Monitor and Mailchimp are more user friendly for the non tech-savvy. All these options are highly customizable though, especially with the API's, so I'd strongly suggest leveraging them behind the scenes instead of completely reinventing the wheel.

I'm not familiar with any "buy once" software, although PHPList comes to mind as an open source platform you can download and run from your own server.