# Building custom newsletter

Tags: email, newsletter

I am about to start building newsletter system, however I have few concerns. I want let users to create their own list of subscribers and let them send emails to subscribed users. User will be able to provide "from" email address and that where is my first concern.

1) I didn't find any information on how to build newsletter in the way that spam filter's wont treat it as spam. First of all my script will be hosted on my hosting (i.e. newsletter.com) , while senders emails will be coming from different domains. I have a feeling that this might at least suspicious for mail providers - if everyone would be allowed to do that you could easily send emails on behalf of someone else.

2) My concern regards dealing with spam users. Assuming that I have 10 users using newsletter systems, out of which 1 users i actually spamming his subscribers. Will that affect my system or only his email?

3) If someone would like to send lot of emails towards  his subscribers (i.e. 5 emails per day). Is there a way to whitelist that? What I mean is that user would have to confirm subscription first but later on system could send more email than typical newsletter sends.

I read about setting correct headers etc. however I didn't find lot of information which would address my concerns. Could you guys provide me with some sources where I could read more about that?

I plan to build it in PHP as I think that is the most common solution but I might be wrong - what are the other options (languages) which I could consider?

Comment: 1) use an email provider, too much work to do alone. 2) It will affect your system. 3) You'll have to build it.

Comment: Thanks, could you give more details regarding 1?

Comment: Maintaining a sender reputation is almost a full job in itself. Use the service of compagnies in the field, ie sendgrid, mailchimp, campaignmonitor, mailgun or others. The sender domains will probably restricted to your(s) domain(s) and the provider one(s).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21012626/how-do-you-become-an-e-newsletter-service-provider?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876040/most-efficient-way-to-send-newsletters?rq=1